# List of one tuple which has multiple items inside

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, tuples

So I haven't been doing python for a while and haven't needed to deal with this before so if i'm making some stupid mistake don't go crazy.

I have a list that is pulled from an SQLite database with `.fetchall()` on the end and it returns a list of one tuple and inside that tuple are all the results:

```
[('Bob', 'Science Homework Test', 'Science homework is a test about Crude Oil development', 'Science-Chemistry', '2019-03-06', '2019-02-27', None, 0)]
```

I want to get inside this tuple to get the items but if I loop the list it doesn't seem to do anything.
I want to do this to `pop()` an item in the list which is `Science-Chemistry` for a HTML select option.
I have had a look before but no one seems to have this same problem with only 1 tuple inside the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest going from the most outside element to the inner one. At the beginning you have a list with one tuple.

```
>>>> result = [('Bob', 'Science Homework Test', 'Science homework is a test about Crude Oil development', 'Science-Chemistry', '2019-03-06', '2019-02-27', None, 0)]
```

To get the tuple, just get the first item of the list:

```
>>> tuple_ = result[0]
('Bob', 'Science Homework Test', 'Science homework is a test about Crude Oil development', 'Science-Chemistry', '2019-03-06', '2019-02-27', None, 0)
```

Then you can loop over it or access it like an array, to get the items:

```
for item in tuple_:
    # do stuff with the item
    print(item)
```

or

```
item = tuple_[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is always going to be exactly only one tuple in the returning list, you can unpack it into meaningfully named variables, the number of which should match the number of output columns in your query:

```
(name, test, description, subject, updated, created, flags, score), = cursor.fetchall()
```

Note the comma after the parentheses that makes it unpack as the first tuple of a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as nested index of list and tuple, i.e first index will give you an element of the list which is a tuple, and second index will give you an element of that tuple.

Let's say the above list is assigned to variable a.

`a = [('Bob', 'Science Homework Test', 'Science homework is a test about Crude Oil development', 'Science-Chemistry', '2019-03-06', '2019-02-27', None, 0)]`

```
a[0] = 1st element of list (a tuple)
a[0][3] = 4th element of that tuple
```